# How do I detect the Computer's operating system?

Tags: usb

I'm working on an emoji keyboard and it requires different input depending on the OS it's connected to. I've written the relevant methods using Arudion's [default Keyboard library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/) and can manually set which one is used. I'm wondering if there is a method or library for Arduino (currently using a Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE) that allows me to detect the OS.

If not, I'll set up a switch, but that'll cost me pins.

Comment: This information is not formally available to a USB peripheral like an Arduino; there might be ways you could "fingerprint" OS behavior from deep in the library code of a Leonardo-type board, but that could trivially change.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. That answer the question. I'm going to have to find a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get the OS from the USB port, why not use the existing keys/inputs to set the mode on startup? That is, if you tell the user to press different combinations of 2 buttons on startup, you have 4 (2 bits => 4 values) different paths on startup:

```
00 => Normal startup, don't change mode
01 => OS 1
10 => OS 2
11 => OS 3
```

Comment: Might do that, but I like the idea of a clear multi option switch for the user to be understand/set at any point.